# How to download an image over HTTPS using Python3

Tags: python-3.x, https

I've seen a variety of answers on this subject, but none appear to work.

I have an [url](https://content3.cdnprado.net/imagenes/Documentos/imgsem/a3/a331/a331fb54-a6d4-4732-8509-daf462aa92bb/dd5afc00-81d5-4e84-aca4-5377a4722391.jpg),  that links directly to an image I wish to download.

```
url = https://content3.cdnprado.net/imagenes/Documentos/imgsem/a3/a331/a331fb54-a6d4-4732-8509-daf462aa92bb/dd5afc00-81d5-4e84-aca4-5377a4722391.jpg
```

My attempts:

```
Using urllib.request.urlretrieve()
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,os.getcwd())
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\mjpvanzuijlen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 248, in urlretrieve
        with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
      File "C:\Users\mjpvanzuijlen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "C:\Users\mjpvanzuijlen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "C:\Users\mjpvanzuijlen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "C:\Users\mjpvanzuijlen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "C:\Users\mjpvanzuijlen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "C:\Users\mjpvanzuijlen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

urlib.request.urlopen()

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as d, open('test.jpg','wb') as  file:
    data = d.read()
    file.write(data)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mjpvanzuijlen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\mjpvanzuijlen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\mjpvanzuijlen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\mjpvanzuijlen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\mjpvanzuijlen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\mjpvanzuijlen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

using requests

```
import requests
response = requests.get(url,verify=False, auth=('user', 'pass'))
with open('file.jpg','w') as fout:
    fout.write(response.read())

C:\Users\mjpvanzuijlen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:852: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Nearly all the related questions either work exclusively for HTTP, or simply do not work for this url.

Comment: In the first example you're not logging in - presumably why the 403 - in the second you are, but you want `response.content` not `response.read()`... (and also you'll want to open the file in `"wb"`)

Comment: How could I log-in on the first example? When manually visiting the browser, I do not need to pass credentials.

Comment: Presumably you've entered the credentials once and have them saved so the browser is sending them automatically on each request. If you really want to do it without using `requests` you'll need to read up on https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.request.html#httpshandler-objects and mixing it with https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler

Comment: How would I do it using requests?

Comment: Did you try what I said in my very first comment?

Comment: Using `response.content` works. If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.